# Will my private github repo code become public if I use Docker automated build?

Tags: docker, private, webhooks

When I wanted to configure the Github webhook for Docker automated builds I got warning:
**"Only add to PUBLIC repo, otherwise Private code will end up on the public Docker index"**.

From the other side, when I go to docker documentation it says:
*During the build process, Docker will copy the contents of your Dockerfile. It will also add it to the Docker Hub for the Docker community (for public repos) or **approved team members/orgs (for private repos)** to see on the repository page.*

So which statment shall I rely on? I have private Github repository and private Docker repository as automated build. If I enable webhook will any of my code get exposed?

**UPDATE AND FINAL RESULT:**

After some discussion with github support the update to Docker webhook documentation was made:
[github-services:90ae97f](https://github.com/github/github-services/commit/90ae97fa2e2a449360ef6926f17925cab5fba90a).
It is safe to link private github repo with private docker repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edit** We have updated the text to give better information and eliminate this confusion. Thanks for raising the issue. https://github.com/github/github-services/pull/946

*Old Text*

> It shouldn't. The text on GitHub is left over from before our private repository service. Now if you make your repo private, your automated build will be private.--

Comment: Thanks Andy, as I understand you are from Docker?

Comment: Yes. I've completed my user profile here on StackOverflow to help people determine that.

Comment: @Andy, generally you disclose this in your answers too ;)

Answer (score 1):

Docker.com gives a single free private repository you can use with an automated build with a private repo on Github or bitbucket. I have not tested this with Github, but currently have a build linked with Bitbucket and it does work.

Make sure you are using a private repo on docker.com though.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Matt, I knew about one private repo on docker, but those messages were confusing.